# Repeat query until condition is met

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, takeuntil

I do an HTTP request to an API that returns 350 records. Each item have a property called "total". I need to select 5 items **randomly** but also, the sum of the property "total" of those 5 items should be less than 30. I think this can be done using takeUntil, but I still don't know how to build the code in order to accomplish that.

```
products$ = combineLatest([
    this._productService.robots$,
    this.refreshProductAction$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, action]) =>
      products.sort(() => (Math.random() - Math.random())).slice(0, 5),
    )
  );
```

The is one example of "expand" operator, but i don't know how to keep track of the sum and the re execute the observable again in case is higher than 50.

Comment: [takeUntil](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeUntil) is probably not what you need. You could use [takeWhile](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeWhile) with [scan](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan)

Comment: @jabaa could you please help me with the logic to build the observable? To be totally honest, I've use both operators but not in a scenario like this one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you receive 350 "products" with just one API invocation which needs to be repeated if the sum of "total" of 5 randomly chosen "products" is higher than 50.

So, if this understanding is correct, I would proceed using `expand` operator to recursively invoke the API until the desired condition is met and then use the `last` operator to notify only the last value emitted, which is the first one satisfying the condition. The following example tries to explain the logic with inline comments.

```
products$ = combineLatest([
  this._productService.robots$,
  this.refreshProductAction$
]).pipe(
  // use expand operator to recursively repeat the API call if the sum is higher than 50, 
  // otherwise return the empty Observable, which means simply to complete the stream
  expand(([products, action]) => {
    const fiveProducts = products.sort(() => (Math.random() - Math.random())).slice(0, 5);
    // use the "reduce" method of Array to calculate the sum
    const sumOfFiveTotals = fiveProducts.reduce((s, p) => s = s + p.total, 0);
    return sumOfFiveTotals > 50 ? 
       // I assume this._productService.robots$, when subscribed, calls the API
       // you can pipe a "delay" operator after this._productService.robots$ if you want to add some delay between subsequent API calls
       this._productService.robots$ :
       EMPTY  // the empty Observable
  }),
  // notifies only the last value emitted by the upstream
  last()
);
```

Comment: Any particular reason you chose `Math.random() - Math.random()` over just `Math.random()`? Just wondering, never seen that before :).

Comment: @ Andrei Gătej no reason. I was just copying the code in the question.